# Quick proof verification on a simple integral property

Tags: proof-verification, definite-integrals

Assuming f is continuous on [-a,a] (I'm not sure how exactly this was written but essentially it just asked to prove this)

$$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)dx = 0$$ assuming f(x) is odd.

This is exactly what I wrote on my midterm:

Since f is continuous on [-a,a] we let F be any antiderivative of f on [-a,a], then $$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)dx = F(x)\bigg|_{-a}^{a} = F(a) - F(-a) = 0$$ by FTOC

I didn't put F(-a) = F(a) since the antiderivative of an odd function is even. I got 0/4 (It was a bonus question so they are a lot harsher, but how is this wrong?)

I asked my TA he wasn't sure because the solution didn't use FTOC to prove it.

Is it not possible to do with FTOC?

Comment: FTOC does not say that any antiderivative of an odd function is even. You should have proved it, and actually I don't have in mind any proof avoiding this particular result.

Comment: Try a u-substitution, $-u = x$. With some work you should get the exact same integral back. What does this mean?

Comment: i had like 40 s to do this question lmao

Comment: This was sent for remark you guys think a mark or so will be given? I seen people get 2/4 just for writting the definition of definite integral or w/e they used to prove it

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would have done it.

Let $f$ be odd and (Riemann) integrable (and hence almost everywhere continuous). Make the change of variable $u = -x$. Then:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-a} ^a f(x) \ dx &= \int_{a} ^{-a} -f(-u) \ du \\
&= \int_{a} ^{-a} f(u) \ du \\
&= -\int_{-a} ^{a} f(u) \ du
\end{align*}

The only real number that is equal to its negative is zero. Hence the integral is zero.

The key: No use of antiderivatives needed here. Just change variables and use some intuition.

Comment: They did it this way in the solutions just took a longer step by seperating the integrals: https://gyazo.com/99619e5a6090c348a9cca8a6f5c234e5

Comment: They're equivalent.